# WebAPI Moq Setup Incorrect...getting invocations must have a corresponding setup

Tags: asp.net-web-api, moq

I am confused as to how I am to setup my Mock object (Yes I do want strict). I have done it other times but this is slightly different. First this is a web api and I'm wondering if my Moq context is being lost and / or this interface has a ref parameter so I'm sure I'm just doing something wrong.

The repository interface:

```
public interface IStuffRepository
{
...code snip....
Stuff GetStuff(Guid stuffId, ref List<ErrorInfo> errorInfo);
}
```

My Moq Implementation:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddValidStuffCorrectResponse()
{
   private Mock<IStuffRepository> _stuffRepository = new Mock<IStuffRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);

   var errInfo = new List<ErrorInfo>(); //ref field

   _stuffRepository.Setup(x => x.GetStuff(It.IsAny<Guid>(), ref errInfo));

   AddStuffController = new AddStuffController(_stuffRepository.Object);

   AddStuffController.AddStuff();
   .....
}
```

The actual code being tested that throws the error:

```
public HttpResponseMessage AddStuff()
{
  var errorInfo = new List<ErrorInfo>();
  ...snip...
  var stuff = stuffRepository.GetStuff(stuffId, ref errorInfo);
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like Moq doens't support matching on [Ref parameters right now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889810/how-to-make-moq-ignore-arguments-that-are-ref-or-out)

Try not using reference paramers. In your case an exception could make more sense than the reference parameter as you use it for error data.