# MOQ object setup scope / context being lost with builder pattern unit test and web api controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am writing unit test for controllers and was running into an issue where it seems the Mocked object is not getting setup when I inject it. If however I create the Mocked object in the controller end point everything works fine. Finally to further complicate things I am doing my unit testing via a fluent builder pattern.

First here is a working snip:

```
public HttpResponseMessage AddSlot(AddSlotRequest requestList)
{
   var errorInfo = new List<ErrorInfo>();

   Mock<IdatRepository> _xRepository = new Mock<IdatRepository>();

   _xRepository.Setup(x => x.GetDat(It.IsAny<Guid>(), ref errorInfo))
     .Returns(new Dat());

 ....snip....

 var crt = _xRepository.Object.GetDat(datId, ref errorInfo);
  //crt object returned as expected from mock

 ....snip

}
```

Now as a heads up this gets a little more involved.

First I have my controller being created by a builder:

```
public class AddSlotControllerBuilder
{
    //private backing field for fluent methods to act upon
    private Mock<IdatRepository> _xRepository = new Mock<IdatRepository>();

    //exposed property for external interactions...
    //not doing any yet but had plans so that is why it is here
    public Mock<IdatRepository> MoqdatRepository { get; private set; }

    //following the builder pattern the build method is called to return 
    //the object after configuration complete
    public AddSlotController Build()
    {

       var errorInfo = new List<ErrorInfo>();
       _xRepository.Setup(x => x.GetDat(It.IsAny<Guid>(), ref errorInfo)).Returns(new Dat());


        //assign private mock field to property
        MoqdatRepository = _xRepository;

        return new AddSlotController(_xRepository.Object);
    }
}
```

Now my unit test uses the builder:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddValidPickupSlotCorrectResponse()
{
   var errorInfo = new List<ErrorInfo>(); //ref field 

   //arrange
   //1. controller
   AddSlotController controller = new AddSlotControllerBuilder().Build();

  //skipping APSR for brevity

   //act
   controller.AddPickupSlot(APSR);

}
```

Finally in the controller

```
  var crt = _xRepository.Object.GetDat(datId, ref errorInfo);
  //crt is null????
```

Any pointers where I'm getting off track would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is being caused by your `GetDat` method taking a ref parameter.  Essentially, unless you're passing the same instance to the call that you're passing to the `Setup`, it will fail to match the Setup.  More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889810/how-to-make-moq-ignore-arguments-that-are-ref-or-out), along with a suggested workaround using RhinoMocks.  I think it'd probably also work with NSubstitute, but I haven't tested that.

Looking at what you're doing though, do you *really* need errorInfo to be passed by ref?  It's an instance of a list class, which presumably your repository might add to.  Is it really going to need to reassign the errorInfo to a different instance of the class?  If not, then you could change the signature to a non-ref one and then set up your mock as follows (either should work):

```
_xRepository.Setup(x => x.GetDat(It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<List<ErrorInfo>>()))
                         .Returns(new Dat());
```

Or

```
_xRepository.Setup(x => x.GetDat(It.IsAny<Guid>(), errorInfo))
                         .Returns(new Dat());
```

Comment: I started on this code base a week ago...taking your wise cue I dug into the ref value and indeed it was being used incorrectly. So I removed pass by ref. Thank You!